# How do I show the the integral exists?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

How do I prove the limit of Lebesgue integral exists and find its value: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} f_n(x)\,dx. $ where $f_n(x)=e^{-x}\cos(x/n)$.

My attempt: I try to apply the Dominated convergence theorem:

i) $|f_{n}(x)|=|e^{-x}\cos(\frac{x}{n})|\leq e^{-x}$.

ii) $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{-x}\cos(\frac{x}{n})= e^{-x}$.

Then $f$ is integrable, and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} f_n(x)\,dx=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$.

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}\cos(\frac{x}{n})\,dx= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}\, dx=1$.

Is this attempt correct? Can I say the integral exist because $f$ is integrable?

Comment: What does it mean for the integral to exist? Integrable means the integral is finite, but the integral is well–defined for any measurable function

Comment: How do I say $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} f_n(x) dx $ exists?

Comment: The title is confusing but I think your approach is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. As a remark, you can solve this (and verify your solution) explicitly.

Let $I_n=\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\cos(x/n)\,dx$. You can actually evaluate this using the bounce back technique. Let $u=\cos(x/n)$, $dv=e^{-x}dx \implies v=-e^{-x}$. Then
\begin{align}
I_n&=uv\Big|_{0}^\infty-\int_0^\infty v\,du \\
&=1-\frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty \sin(x/n)e^{-x}\,dx \\
&\stackrel{IBP}{=}1-\frac{1}{n^2}\int_0^\infty\cos(x/n)e^{-x}\,dx \\
&=1-\frac{1}{n^2}I_n
\end{align}
This implies
$$
I_n=\frac{1}{1+1/n^2}.
$$

Comment: Alternatively, $I_n=\Re\int_0^\infty\exp(-(1-i/n)x)dx=\Re\frac{1}{1-i/n}=\frac{1}{1+1/n^2}$.

Comment: I hate you. Just kidding, but I didn't think of it in this way. Nice solution :)